# MySQL how to remove records in a table that are in another table

Tags: sql, inner-join, subtraction

I have table A with close to 15000 entries. I have a second table B with 7900 entries with a common field with table A.

I need to extract into a third temporary tableC all entries from table A except the ones that also appear in table B. Simple as it may sound, i havent found a way to do it. The closest i got was this:

```
INSERT INTO tableC
SELECT * 
FROM tableA
    INNER JOIN tableB
        ON tableA.field IS NOT tableB.field
```

This SQL just selects everything in tableA, even entries that are in tableB.

Any ideas where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What if you try this?

```
INSERT INTO tableC 
SELECT * 
FROM tableA 
WHERE tableA.field NOT IN (SELECT tableB.field FROM tableB)
```

Or you can try the alternate EXISTS syntax

```
INSERT INTO tableC 
SELECT * 
FROM tableA 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE tableB.field = tableA.field)
```

Comment: excellent! This worked like a charm. Hadn't though of simply using a sub-select.